# website Login issue Requestverification using WinHTTPrequest.5.1/Microsoft.XMLHTTP in VBA

Tags: vba, authentication, xmlhttprequest, msxml, winhttprequest

I am trying to automating login and download data for the website(https://indexes.nasdaqomx.com/).
My code is failing for authenticiation, where is the issue, my WinHttpReq.responseText top portion says as below:

```
 </header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid spacer">
    <div class="span12">
        <p class="textCenter">
            We're sorry your request could not be fulfilled. Rest assured we have been notifed and will resolve this issue shortly.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My VBA code is as below:

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub DownloadFile()

Dim myuser As String
Dim MyPass As String
Dim sHTML As String
myuser = "xxxxxx"
MyPass = "xxxxxx"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

WinHttpReq.Open "POST", "https://indexes.nasdaqomx.com/Account/LogOn", True

WinHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
WinHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
WinHttpReq.send "UserName=xxxxxx&Password=xxxxxxx"
Sleep (6000)
Debug.Print WinHttpReq.readyState
If WinHttpReq.readyState = 4 Then
sHTML = WinHttpReq.responseText
'this below line result shows We're sorry your request could not be fulfilled
Debug.Print sHTML
End If
Sleep (5000) ' delay 4 second

WinHttpReq.Open "GET", "https://indexes.nasdaqomx.com/Index/ExportWeightings/NDX?tradeDate=2015-08-19T00:00:00.000&timeOfDay=SOD", True
Debug.Print WinHttpReq.readyState
WinHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
WinHttpReq.send
Sleep (5000) ' delay 4 second
Debug.Print WinHttpReq.readyState

MyURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
    ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
    oStream.SaveToFile "D:\Visual Basic Programming\Macro\nasdaqomx\SODWeightings_20150819_NDX.xlsx", 2
    oStream.Close
End If

End Sub
```

So where is the problem ? I have valid credential for this as manual login is working fine. Below is a screenshot of html code of that page. It shows some kind of request verification code but it is different every time I have noticed. Can anybody tell me how to do login programmatically in the webpage ?

[image: login page html screenshot]

Comment: You are not reading the hidden input element for the token and passing it back in the send string. Sometimes you need to pass back seemingly innocuous input elements like the submit as well. Best to use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to examine what POST string is passed and to where during a manual login.

Comment: I was suspecting it....could u plz post the code how to read the hidden input element for the token and send it back

Answer (score 2):

I cannot post 'the code' but I can post some framework. If you have trouble getting this working then use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to examine the hidden POST string on a successful login and duplicate it.

The method is to first GET the page and read the token. Add the token and any other incidental <input> form elements to your send string and POST it back.

I've made some vars public as they could be used in other procedures. Make sure you don't have two `Option Explicit` declarations at the top of your module sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Public pUSR As String
Public pPWD As String
'you might need this elsewhere; make it a public string
Public pTOKENID As String
'you might need one of these too
Public pJSESSIONID As String
'you want to go here
Public Const csLOGINpg = "https://indexes.nasdaqomx.com/Account/LogOn"
Public Const csTOKENnm = "__RequestVerificationToken"

Sub mcr_XML_LogIn()
    Dim htmlBDY As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument, xmlHTTP As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60

    Dim iEL As Long, xmlSend As String

    On Error GoTo bm_Err_Report

    pJSESSIONID = vbNullString
    pTOKENID = vbNullString
    pUSR = "xxxxxx"
    pPWD = "xxxxxxx"

    With xmlHTTP
        .Open "GET", csLOGINpg, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
        .SetRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
        .send

        htmlBDY.body.innerHTML = .responseText

        If CBool(htmlBDY.getElementsByTagName("form").Length) Then
            With htmlBDY.getElementsByTagName("form")(0)
                For iEL = 0 To (.getElementsByTagName("input").Length - 1)
                    If htmlBDY.getElementsByTagName("input")(iEL).Name = csTOKENnm Then
                        pTOKENID = htmlBDY.getElementsByTagName("input")(iEL).Value
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next iEL
            End With
        End If

        .Open "POST", csLOGINpg, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .SetRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
        'you may need to send a JSESSIONID cookie; Fiddler will tell you this and other stuff
        '.SetRequestHeader "Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" & pJSESSIONID
        xmlSend = csTOKENnm & Chr(61) & pTOKENID & "&RememberMe=false&UserName=" & pUSR & "&Password=" & pPWD
        Debug.Print xmlSend

        .send xmlSend
        htmlBDY.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With  'done with the xmlHTTP object for now

    'do something with what you received here (maybe check for a successful log-in)
    Debug.Print Left(htmlBDY.body.innerHTML, 1024)

    GoTo bm_Safe_Exit

bm_Err_Report:
    Debug.Print Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Set htmlBDY = Nothing
    Set xmlHTTP = Nothing
End Sub
```

Yes, this is based on a MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60 object but it is one that IO had laying around that could be easily redacted for public distribution.

> If you use this code without changing it to WinHTTP then you will need the microsoft XML v6.0 and Microsoft internet Controls reference libraries added to the VBE's Tools ► References.

I ran this through to make sure I was contacting the right page. The xmlSend string was,

```
 __RequestVerificationToken=RHr1FDomqqHEZQJPmMVqdwoFKVsK43uE3j1g+IWRF3nHqmxZGDyAxpUWqes2XCKgHVhHPnpLCcn3EOIKHJ30EoQbBOhV16IkS7oqPQm+3x5cex0GAWzfUYuzOGGYM35/Xa6jsXF7YsN78b3TzadIwS/8EENNdA6jSqtXgH7cDU/FNIRuMJQbO9dplwtglcg8&RememberMe=false&UserName=xxxxxx&Password=xxxxxxx
```

... so it was retrieving the token. The first 1024 characters of the .innerHTML was:

```
<HEADER id=headerContent class=spacer>
<DIV id=logoRow class=row-fluid>
<DIV class=container>
<DIV class=row-fluid>
<DIV class=span6><A class=noLinkExternal href="http://nasdaqomx.com/"><IMG id=Nasdaqlogo style="MARGIN-RIGHT: -3px" alt="Nasdaq logo" src="about:/Content/Images/nasdaq_logo.png"></A> <A href="about:/"><IMG id=logo alt="Nasdaq Global Indexes" src="about:/Content/Images/global_indexes.png"></A> </DIV>
<DIV class=span6>
<DIV class=floatRight>
<UL id=loginList class=hideListStyle>
<LI class=hidden-phone><A id=LoginLink class=noLinkExternal>Log In</A></LI>
<LI class=visible-phone><A href="about:/Account/LogOn">Log In</A></LI>
<LI><A href="about:/Home/IndexData">Register</A></LI></UL><INPUT id=siteSearch class=ui-autocomplete-input value=Search> </DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV>
<DIV id=menuContainer>
<DIV class=container>
<DIV class=row-fluid>
<DIV class=span12>
<DIV id=LoginPanel class=inputForm>
<FORM method=post action=/Account/LogOn><INPUT type=hidden value=EpSOScbAMNDv1lIjBnm8Xew4Rn
```

Hope this helps. Use Fiddler to settle any problems. Sorry but I cannot do much else without valid credentials.

Comment: can u recommend any applied book to learn website java login mechanism technical stuff

Comment: Glad that was helpful. I'm sorry but I don't have any reference material to recommend but the [xmlHTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/new/xmlhttp?show=all&sort=newest) forum here is good and I contribute when I can.

Comment: could u post framework for logoff action in this page

Comment: Honestly, you just need to destroy the xmlHTTP object. If you create a new one immediately, it will not have echoes of the first. In practise however, I respect the webmaster's intentions and use the log off page as the URL in a GET action.

Comment: Hey! I just realized. If you are looking to log off, then you must have successfully logged on! Well done!

Comment: Could u plz share ur email to purnendumaity@gmail.com, now help of fiddler i am doing .SetRequestHeader "Cookie", "ASP.NET_SessionId=" & pJSESSIONID    but post log in the GET request now either it's a dummy 2 col data in excel(as if no login) or xmlHTTP.responseText is -2147483638 - The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available. seems i have to wait till xmlHTTP.Status = 200...so cranky

Comment: If you want me to try the routine with the credetials then you can find an email address at my profile page [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/a05bdd23-6c19-4f50-9b4a-3c6ae7d72590#user-profile-tab-profile).

Comment: Thanks Sir, in a parallel effort I have used IE objects and later UIAutomationCore.dll framework for download pop-up frame alert handling so as of now it is fine...but definitely I will contact u in this XML approach because that is much more stable and fast.